# Why does dynamic_cast give nullptr with private inheritance here?

Tags: c++, inheritance, private

Could someone explain this to me:

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

struct B : private A {
    void foo() {
        B* b = new B;
        std::list<A*> list = {b};
        B* back = dynamic_cast<B*>(list.back());
        std::cout << back << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.foo();  // nullptr
}
```

From what I understand, only B is aware that B is derived from A.  foo() is a member function of B.  So dynamic_casting from A* to B* should be fine inside B::foo().  So why is the result nullptr?  Same thing goes if it is protected inheritance.  Change the inheritance to public, and everything is fine.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way `dynamic_cast<T>(v)` executes its run-time checks is specified in §5.2.7 [expr.dynamic.cast]/p8:

> If `C` is the class type to which `T` points or refers, the run-time
>   check logically executes as follows:
>
> - If, in the most derived object pointed (referred) to by `v`, `v` points (refers) to a `public` base class subobject of a `C` object,
>     and if only one object of type `C` is derived from the subobject
>     pointed (referred) to `o` by `v` the result points (refers) to that
>     `C` object.
> - Otherwise, if `v` points (refers) to a `public` base class subobject of the most derived object, and the type of the most derived object
>     has a base class, of type `C`, that is unambiguous and `public`, the
>     result points (refers) to the `C` subobject of the most derived
>     object.
> - Otherwise, the run-time check fails.

Note that the check only succeeds for public bases.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Rules are rules I guess.  Then I think the definition of private inheritance should include the above rule, because the definitions I read misled me otherwise.